# jquery toggle button value

Tags: jquery

In the below code when the play button is clicked Its value should be changed to pause and when pause is clicked the other function should be called .How to do this using jquery toggle

```
  <input type="button" onclick ="play" value="play"/>
   <script>
     function play()
     {
               play_int();
           //   Button value to be changed to pause
     }   

  And when pause play_pause();
```

Comment: what you have tried till now???

Comment: Don't use inline event handlers. With jQuery it does not really make sense also.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Give your button an ID:

```
<input type="button" id="play" value="play"/>
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
$('#play').click(function() {
   if ($(this).val() == "play") {
      $(this).val("pause");
      play_int();
   }
   else {
      $(this).val("play");
     play_pause();
   }
});
```

Or a slightly tidier version like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#play').click(function() {
       // if the play button value is 'play', call the play function
       // otherwise call the pause function
       $(this).val() == "play" ? play_int() : play_pause();
    });
});

function play_int() {
    $('#play').val("pause");
    // do play
}

function play_pause() {
    $('#play').val("play");
    // do pause
}
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/vPh6R/1/)

Answer (score 14):

try ( in jQuery < **1.9** )

```
$("input[type='button']").toggle(
    function(){
        $(this).val("Pause");
    }, 
    function(){
        $(this).val("Play");
    }
);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/U93aE/)

Note: The `toggle` event was deprecated in 1.8 and removed in 1.9

Comment: Will this work with initial value ? I mean if the button is already set to Pause, will it toggle to Play ? I'm not sure.

Comment: @diEcho its not working in jQuery 1.9 and above versions. Is there any other way to do like this?

Comment: @LakshmanaKumar The toggle event was deprecated in 1.8 and removed in 1.9  read : http://forum.jquery.com/topic/problem-with-toggle-function-in-jquery-1-9-1

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#play_button_id').toggle(play,play_pause);
```

this will trigger the play() function when you click the button for the first time

and the play_pause() when you click the button for the second time

Comment: No, it won't. Unless these functions return with another function :). You should use `toggle(play, play_pause)`.

Answer (score 2):

I would say

```
statuses = ['Play', 'Pause'];
$('#btn_play').val(
    $('#btn_play').val() == statuses[0]
    ? statuses[1] : statuses[0]
);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simplest idea can be this

```
function play(action) {
 { 
   if(action=='play') { 
      play_int(); 
      $("#btn_play").val('pause');
   }
   else { 
      pause_int(); 
      $("#btn_play").val('play');
   }
}

$("#btn_play").click(function() {
   val = $(this).val();
   play(val);
}
```